# Is it intentional that chat history of a removed message is still viewable if you have the ID of the message?

Tags: discussion, chat, revisions-list

This relates to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com).

If I have the ID of a message, and know the correct format for the history page (basically just by opening up the history of a message that hasn't been removed), is it intentional that I am allowed to view the history of a removed question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might have to check, but my *understanding* is that this is limited to the person who posted the message, and owners of the room. Do you have an example?

Comment: Agh, suits me right for being a bit slow with posting this. I discovered it a few days ago, it's no longer possible. I am given a page not existing. Or.... perhaps it's limited to questions that was edited before removed? Let me test that...

Comment: Yep, fixed. I can see my own, but not yours. I could see others messages a few days ago, but I was slooow. Anyway...

Comment: @Lasse nothing was "fixed" here AFAIK ('cos nothing was broken); simply you must have been a room owner.